Default Domain Policy allows remote desktop connections, but Windows 11 machine has them disabled
On my Windows Active Directory Network (it has three domain controllers which are in sync), there is a Default Domain Policy which allows remote desktop connections and r.d. connections are thus enabled on all devices in the network. The policy item is named (in German) "Remoteverbindungen für Benutzer mithilfe der Remotedesktopdienste zulassen" (allow remote connections for users using remote desktop services) and is set to "activated/enabled".
However on one Windows 11 Professional device connected to the network, gpresult says that this same Default Domain Policy prohibits remote desktop connections (fDenyTSConnections is true).
I can't see why this happens, do you have any suggestions? Thanks!

Do you have an AD domain? If so, have you set this policy on the AD domain server? I assume you are running Professional not Home.

Yes it is a AD domain, and the policy is set on the domain controller.

And it's professional, you are right

Does gpresult tell you which DC the policy was obtained from? Can you manually check whether the files in sysvol are in sync across all DCs? Are there other policies applied or do you just edit the default policy for everything?

"The policy is set on the domain controller." - Enabled or disabled?

No, gpresult did not say which DC the policy was obtained from. I checked, the DCs are all in sync. There are many other policies applied, but the remote desktop is defined in the Default Domain Policy. The item is named (in German) "Remoteverbindungen für Benutzer mithilfe der Remotedesktopdienste zulassen" (allow remote connections for users using remote desktop services) and is set to "activated/enabled".
